Convert foreach to select statement
I have below code written in foreach loop, I want to convert it to linq select method.
I tried following, but it's not working. So any idea on this

In what way is this not working?  Are you getting an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?

Do you understand that you have executed N*4 queries and with right LINQ query you can do that effectively? Accepted answer makes the problem worse.

var bidsData = bidderDatas.Select( bd => new BidderDataDTO() {
        TenderId = bd.TenderId,
                         // I think you may want  "bd.TenderId" here  ˇ
        ClosingDate = _context.Tenders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == tenderid)?.ClosingDate,
        CompanyName = _context.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == x.CompanyId)?.CompanyName,
        FullName = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.userid == bd.CreatedUser)?.Select(x => $"{x.Firstname} {x.Lastname}")
        Price = bd.Price,
        Email = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid == x.CreatedUser)?.Email
   });

Note this creates an IEnumerable instead of a List, but that's often better, and if you really need a List you can call .ToList() to get it.
We could probably improve performance a little more by extending the lambda to avoid needing to  call FirstOrDefault() on the same Users collection more than once. But if I really cared about performance I'd write raw SQL. I tend to reserve linq queries for in-memory collection types or only the simplest table => object mappings.
